# Strange (?) behavior with virtual keyword with g++ (Ubuntu)

Tags: c++, g++

I was going through notes about virtual destructors and virtual functions. Now, when I tried to write a simple code to validate my learning,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base{
    public:
    Base (){
        cout << "Constructing base" <<endl;
    }
    void doSomething (){
        cout << "inside void " << endl;
    }
    ~Base (){
        cout << "Destructing base" << endl;
    }
};
class Derived : public Base{
    public:
    Derived(){
        cout << "Constructing derived" << endl;
    }
    void doSomething (){
        cout << "inside derived void " << endl;
    }
    ~Derived(){
        cout << "Destructing derived" << endl;
    }
};
int main(){
    Derived *d = new Derived();
    d->doSomething();
    delete d;
}
```

Shouldn't I expect an output like so:

```
Constructing base
Constructing derived
inside void
Destructing base
```

because I didn't use the virtual keyword for the destructors of both derived and base? Can you please explain virtual functions and virtual destructors in view of this sample?

I get this output:

```
Constructing base
Constructing derived
inside derived void 
Destructing derived
Destructing base
```

I'm confused.

I use `g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3` in Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Your pointer is declared as `Derived *`. So its static type is `Derived *`, hence the methods from `Derived` are called. (Not having virtual functions means that the _declared type_ of the pointer (aka static type) is used as the basis for selecting which function to call.)

Comment: Ah, so if I make destructor virtual, and I do `Base * d = new Derived(); delete d; `, the virtual destructor of Derived will also be called?

Comment: Yes, if you make the destructor virtual. That's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the correct output.

```
Derived *d = new Derived();
d->doSomething();
```

It's calling the Derived class member function. For the runtime function call dispatch mechanism to work, you need to qualify the member functions with `virtual` keyword. Also you should write -

```
Base *d = new Derived();
```

In the above case, static type of `d` is different from the dynamic type. So, derived class member function will be called at runtime. Also, `Base` class destructor should be `virtual` in such scenario.